# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) Imprimir Números

Tags: c

Escrevi um algorítmo que imprime todos os números inteiros em um intervalo fechado de A até B, com A e B inteiros. Entretanto, quando estava compilando e montando o arquivo no bash do linux, ocorreu um "segmentation fault". Alguém sabe me explicar o por quê?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int imprimir(int a, int b){
int i;
   if(a=b){
return a;
   }else{
 if(a<b){
   for(i=a;i<=b;a++){
     printf("%d",a);
}
   }else{
     for(i=b;i<=a;b++){
        printf("%d",b);  
   }
  }
 }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
 int a, b;

 printf("Forneca dois numeros quaisquer");
 scanf("%d%d",a,b);
 if(a<0 && b<0){
 printf("Digite um numero inteiro nao negativo");
 scanf("%d %d",a,b);
}

imprimir(a,b);
return imprimir;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código continha alguns erros. Um exemplo é o primeiro `if`. Acredito que você queria fazer uma comparação (`==`), e não uma atribuição (`=`). Outro erro era a falta do `&` na hora de ler com `scanf()`.

O `return imprimir;` também não fazia sentido. Eu corrigi para você (pelo menos da forma que entendi o problema). No seu enunciado você disse que queria o intervalo fechado entre A e B inteiros, mas estava criando uma restrição para os inteiros não negativos no código. Lembre-se que se o exercício deve funcionar para os inteiros, ele abrange também os valores negativos. O código abaixo funciona tanto para positivos quanto negativos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void imprimir(int a, int b) {
    int menor, maior;
    if (a > b) { menor = b; maior = a; }
    else { menor = a; maior = b; }
    while (menor != maior + 1) {
        printf("%i ", menor);
        menor++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    int a, b;

    printf("Forneca dois numeros quaisquer: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    imprimir(a,b);
}
```

*Código editado*: apenas troquei o tipo de retorno da função imprimir, já que ela deve apenas imprimir e não precisa retornar um `int`. Mas deixe da forma que você está mais acostumado. :-)

Espero que eu tenha conseguido compreender o seu problema corretamente para ajudá-lo.